# How to save rendered size to intrinsic size in html?

Tags: html, css

So I was wondering how I save an image file, but when I tried to save the image, only the original file was saved and not the rendered image size.

```
<!--just a sample codes-->
<center>
    <image src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/Python-logo-notext.svg/800px-Python-logo-notext.svg.png" width="657" height=auto></image>
</center>
```

It downloaded as an 800x800 size. Any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work by removing the back `</image>` tag. Can you try first and see if its working?

```html
<image src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/Python-logo-notext.svg/800px-Python-logo-notext.svg.png" width="200" height="200">
```

Comment: Even removing the `</image>` tag doesn't change anything

Comment: this may have to do with the `<center>` tag, as its not supported if youre using html5. Try removing the tag, also put actual numbers in height to see whether its working.

Comment: I mean, everything's working fine. My point was, when I downloaded the image, the width and height changed to, let's say, 657x657, but when I downloaded it, it downloaded the original of the image, so it's not using the rendered size.

Comment: There is no command for changing an image size. Image dimensions are ‘properties’ which can be expressed in either the HTML <img> element, as `width="150"` `height="100"` attributes in the tag; or, the CSS as style rules applying to specific images. Read this [link](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/529458a5f10c609b5b0008d1#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20command%20for,rules%20applying%20to%20specific%20images.)

Answer (score 0):

Rendered size depends on view and layout overrides. Without any CSS overrides or viewport limitations the image is displayed with Intrinsic size which is the actual image size. That means even if a 200px * 200px image renders as 2000px * 2000px via CSS when you download it, you will get a 200 * 200 Image.

Only way to get the rendered image size is to take a screenshot of the image as display on your screen.

[https://www.ohmycrawl.com/technical-seo/intrinsic-size-vs-rendered/#:~:text=Intrinsic%20size%20refers%20to%20the,after%20it%20has%20been%20displayed](https://www.ohmycrawl.com/technical-seo/intrinsic-size-vs-rendered/#:%7E:text=Intrinsic%20size%20refers%20to%20the,after%20it%20has%20been%20displayed).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Intrinsic_Size

Comment: Please consider including all the necessary information to solve this problem directly in your answer and not rely only on links. If the link become inactive in the future, your answer becomes useless.